# How to tell dwm to launch an app on the secondary screen

Tags: x11

I have the following **[rule](http://dwm.suckless.org/customisation/rules)** in my dwm config file:

```
{ "Quodlibet",       NULL,     NULL,  1 << 4,    False,       -1 },
```

If instructs dwm to always launch an app titled *Quodlibet* on the fifth tag, a tag being the equivalent of a virtual desktop.

What if I wanted to have this app launched on a secondary screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last element of the array determines which screen is used. Now, number the windows such the the primary monitor (the one sitting on the left) is `0`. In effect, the line above would then be:

```
{ "Quodlibet",       NULL,     NULL,  1 << 4,    False,       1 },
```